# Removing trails from mapbox map

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android, mapbox-marker

We are currently working on outdoor map for mountain in Croatia. Some trails that are included are no longer available to general public. How long does it take for Mapbox to remove trails from map?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox doesn't publish any information about their data curation practises. "Months to years" is as good a guess as any.

Comment: Hi Steve,

Can we ask Mapbox to remove certain trails that are no longer in use?

Best regards

Comment: Only one way to find out: https://www.mapbox.com/contact/

Answer (score 0):

If you know the names or other identifying info of the trails that you want to remove, you can use a runtime filter to hide them from the map style that you're using.